# Input constraints while comparing different DFT calculated properties for the same material but different atomic arrangement

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, k-points, convergence-test, numerical-convergence

Let's consider a fictitious `AB` type binary alloy. `AB` is known to exist in a `B2` type ordered structure. We want to compare the DoS (density of states) between this structure for `AB` and a completely disordered structure. On disordering, `AB` would become a `BCC` type random solid solution.

Now, what are the inputs for a DFT code that we must consider carefully? Should the k-mesh spacing, plane wave energy cut-off, and smearing width ($\sigma$) be the same for both to be able to compare them or should we converge these for each of them individually?

Comment: Could you give two POSCARs for your AB and BCC? The difference between both decide your input cards.

Answer (score 6):

The best strategy when performing convergence tests is to directly converge the quantity you are interested in. This "quantity" can be a straight-forward physical property, like the band gap of a material, or a *composite* (for lack of a better word) property. In your case, you are interested in comparing the electronic density of states (DOS) between two compounds, so my suggestion would be to build a relevant composite property.

Here is a naïve proposal for your case. Let $g_A(E)$ and $g_B(E)$ be the densities of states of the two compounds you are comparing, and let $(E_1,E_2)$ be the energy range over which you want to compare the densities of states. Then I can define a quantity $\Delta$ that measures the difference between the two densities of states, for example as:

$$
\Delta=\frac{1}{E_2-E_1}\int_{E_1}^{E_2} \sqrt{\left[g_A(E)-g_B(E)\right]^2} dE.
$$

My suggestion would be to converge $\Delta$ with respect to the relevant parameters. If you individually converge $g_A$ and $g_B$, then their difference should also be converged, but converging $\Delta$ instead may provide important computational gains because there may be some "cancellation of errors" in the convergence of the *difference* between $g_A$ and $g_B$, which is what you are really interested in.

As to the parameters you should converge, I agree that $\mathbf{k}$-points (both for the self-consistent and non-self-consistent parts of the calculation), energy cut-off, and smearing width are important. Depending on what you want to achieve with the comparison, it may also be important to play around with the limits $(E_1,E_2)$ in an expression like the one for $\Delta$ above.

Answer (score 4):

To compare calculations, it’s best to have all the calculation parameters possible the same, including the k-mesh spacing, plane wave energy cut-off, and the Brillouin zone integration method (with the same smearing width, if applicable). The settings must also be sufficiently converged for each case.

In your example, if the B2 case a tighter k-point spacing while the disordered case required a higher energy cutoff to be converged, then the calculations to be compared should use both the tighter k-point spacing and the higher energy cutoff.

It’s also key to highlight that the calculations should have the same k-point *spacing*, i.e. no matter the crystal size, the density of points in the volume is the same. This pattern should be applied to any setting related to an extrinsic property, such as the k-point sampling, since cell volume is an extrinsic property.

Some settings like smearing width are complicated, because there’s not necessarily a *converged* value in terms of correctness. Too small or too large can cause issues, as discussed in [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2025/1179).